# Exclude URL's from sanitize_html_classes

Tags: custom-field, save-post, autosave

I've searched through the similar questions but found nothing.

I've coded a meta box for adding custom URL's which get added to buttons on single posts but when the URL is added to the meta box field on the Edit Post screen and saved, it strips the URL from this :

```
http://example.com
```

To this :

```
httpexamplecom
```

I assume because of the sanitize_html_classes function which is used with the save_post function like this :

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'projecturl_save', 1, 2 );
function projecturl_save( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( ! isset( $_POST['projecturl'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $data = wp_parse_args(
        
        $_POST['projecturl'],
        [
            '_custom_projecturl' => '',
        ]
    );

    $data = array_map( 'custom_sanitize_html_classes', $data );

    save_custom_fields( $data, 'projecturl_save', 'projecturl_nonce', $post );

}
```

I'm using a custom function save_sanitize_html_classes function but there's nothing in there that strips out anything so it must have something to do with the [sanitize_html_classes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_html_class/) function.

```
function custom_sanitize_html_classes( $classes, $return_format = 'input' ) {

    if ( 'input' === $return_format ) {
        $return_format = is_array( $classes ) ? 'array' : 'string';
    }

    $classes = is_array( $classes ) ? $classes : explode( ' ', $classes );

    $sanitized_classes = array_map( 'sanitize_html_class', $classes );

    if ( 'array' === $return_format ) {
        return $sanitized_classes;
    }

    return implode( ' ', $sanitized_classes );

}
```

I can remove sanitization ( and when i do it works ) but i prefer to filter it to exclude characters in URL's. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But sanitize_html_classes is for class= attribute values. Why use that to sanitize URLs?

Comment: How would i sanitize URL's? I guess i could use esc_url_raw or esc_url but what if the user enters something other than a URL?

Comment: Why not use PHP's [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) before the save, encoded characters are not striped (if I rememebr correctly)

Comment: If you give esc_url something other than an URL then it should return an empty string. Is that what you want, or did you want to allow that? PHP also has a filter_var() you can use to check if something is an URL, and there's an old OWASP library for filtering URLs too.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/3276/rup Whatever best practice is for meta box text fields for URL's

Comment: if you have a string with already only the url, doesnt need to be sanitize. sanitize is to remove html code from there, if already is clean. its ok.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/198152/tiago-calado Yes but happens if the user puts PHP or something else in there and NOT a URL?

Comment: (For the future, if you want to flag us in a reply then that's @, e.g. @Rup for me. I didn't get any notification for the link. But there are some circumstances when it notifies us automatically, e.g. if there's only one comment or one poster here - you don't need it always.)

Answer (score 0):

On input, [esc_url_raw()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url_raw/) is the correct function to use which replaces [sanitize_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_url/)

Example :

```
$custom_field = esc_url_raw( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_custom_url', true ) );
```